# Interbase query to XML

Tags: sql, xml, interbase

I have an Interbase database that I need to pull data from but cannot seems to put it into xml.  I have a table named addresses, and need to get ADDR1, ADDR2, STATE, ZIP, GARAGING.  I can get the info using SQL easily but I need to output it as XML.  I did some research and found:

http://support.codegear.com/article/35491

But it is a little confusing to me.  And by a little I mean a lot.

Can anyone explain how to output as XML or maybe better explain the process?

Comment: Wow, interbase. I used to do quite an amount interbase. When I used it many years ago, interbase SQL was actually translated into GDML. I had to write quite an amount of gdml thro the qli facility, which allowed me to do more things than SQL. Do you .gdb is named after the town/city of Groton in Massachusetts?

Answer (score 1):

Seems clear enough aside from a few glaring faults.

You need to set up the form with the controls mentioned in the code.

Put some sql in the sql one, click the button.
It put the sql in ibsql1, executes against the chosen database, the component whaps out the content as xml, specified by the other controls into a Tstringstream, and then assigns the result of that to a memo so you can see it.

PS unlike this person, don't put start transaction in one method and commit in another, that's asking for a bug fest.

Looks like given MyDatabase witha Table called MyTable with columns MyName and MyPhone

Header tag being set to empty
DatabaseTag set to the database name, table tag to table name, and row tag to say Contact, you'd get something like

```
<MyDataBase>
  <MyTable>
    <Contact>
      <MyName>Tony</MyName>
      <MyPhone>+44 999</MyPhone>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <MyName>Fred</MyName>
      <MyPhone>+44 100</MyPhone>
    </Contact>
  </MyDataBase>
</MyTable>
```

You shpould be able to morph it into something more sensible, like passing to sql to a function that returns a Stream.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what the SQL would look like for this?  Sorry but I'm still not sure of what to do :/

Comment: Thought you'd done that bit Select Addr1,Addr2,zip From Addresses or some such.

Comment: Sorry I didn't phrase that right.  I have the SQL to get my data:
select ADDR1, ADDR2, STATE, GARAGE_ZIP from ADDRESS.  But but I still don't understand how to output this as XML.  What would the code look like to output it as XML

Comment: I'mm missing something here. Have you got the example app working?